# uWSGI and Postgresql connection pool

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, uwsgi

I've been trying to find an answer to this but can't seem to find it.

I have a uWSGI application that is running 2 processors

> processes = 2

And within my app, I have this

```
postgreSQL_pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 4,
                                                     user=db_username,
                                                     password=db_password,
                                                     host=db_host,
                                                     port=db_port,
                                                     database=db_name)
```

So, does this mean that I have 2 "processors" for my web app and 8 (max) connections in the pool when my app runs (4 pooling threads per uWSGI process)?

I'm very confused as how uWSGI does threading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two connection pools each with 4 connections.